# Unwanted texture rendering

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

Currently i am using libgdx 1.4.1 having a problem of unwanted texture in various points of my game ,i am sharing screen shot of one such problem(black character comes with popup of exit). In game, i have Texture Atlas(spritesheet) of colored character instead of these black character.

[image: game screenshot]

Condition for happening :

```
1. On ads loading(banner/interstitial admob ads).
2. In app purchase.
3. sometime on google leaderboard.
4. On resume after home button press(rarely).
5. On resume in case of exit (sometime if i commented assetmannage.dispose()).
```

Problem.

```
1.Random texture any where.
2.black fonts/texture after resume
```

My code Implementation.
I am using assest manager class to load all texture.

```
public void create() {    
    FileHandleResolver resolver=new InternalFileHandleResolver();
    assetManager = new AssetManager(resolver);
    Texture.setAssetManager(assetManager);
    assetManager.setLoader(FreeTypeFontGenerator.class, new FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader(resolver));
    assetManager.setLoader(BitmapFont.class, ".ttf", new FreetypeFontLoader(resolver));

    Texture.setAssetManager(assetManager);
    //loading fonts.............
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        int size=9*(1+i);
        FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter fontParameterS=new FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
        fontParameterS.fontFileName=Constants._strungFontPath;
        fontParameterS.fontParameters.size=size;
        fontParameterS.fontParameters.characters="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890\"!`?'.,;:|/@\\^$-%+=#_&";
        assetManager.load("stungFont"+size+".ttf",BitmapFont.class,fontParameterS);
    }   
}   

public void loadingResourceDuringSplash() {
    //Loading some CSV,s
    Pixmap pixmap=new Pixmap(20,20, Format.RGBA4444);
    pixmap.setColor(1, 1, 1,1);
    pixmap.fill();
    blankTexture=new Texture(pixmap);
    // pixmap.dispose();    
    loadAssetsINAssetManager();
}    

private void loadAssetsINAssetManager() {
    assetManager.load("img/Moles.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);   
    assetManager.load("img/tutorial.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
    assetManager.load("img/Main_BG.png", Texture.class);    
    assetManager.load("img/tree.png", Texture.class);
    //some other file texture to..
}
public void render() {
    super.render();
    assetManager.update();
    sleep();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    //  assetManager.dispose();  // makes problem less frequent 
    //  blankTexture.dispose();
    //  pointTexture.dispose();
}

@Override
public void resume() {
    super.resume();
    Texture.setAssetManager(assetManager);
    loadAssetsINAssetManager();
    assetManager.finishLoading();    
}
```

Comment: Are you storing any texture references with static variables?

Comment: i am using blanktexture as static variable.

Comment: In some places i am initialise some staic variable like static font1=assestManager.get(font) etc

Comment: All of these static references could be causing your problem. If you static reference a font, you are indirectly keeping the Texture object alive through the font's reference to it. When an Activity is closed and reopened, all the static references from before are maintained, and so Textures will leak and won't work correctly if you don't load them again. Basically: never use static object references with libgdx unless you know exactly what the implications are. Also, you should not comment out diposing of assetManager, etc or you will leak memory.

Comment: Ok,I try to remove all static references.Thanks for help

Comment: I still have the prb. Is there is any other approach,to check this prb.